# Почему очень похожие регулярные выражения работают по разному?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть две строки:

```
let str1 = `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css">`;
let str2 = `<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/script.min.js">`;
```

Я хочу найти в них части `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=` и `<script type="text/javascript" src =`. Для поиска в первой строке я использовал такое регулярное выражение:

```
/<link.*href=/
```

Для второй строки такое:

```
/<script.*src=/
```

Я увидел, что регулярка с фрагменом`href=`подходит для первой строки, но регулярка с фрагментом `src=` - не подходит для второй. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит? И регулярки и строки вроде бы очень похожи.

Еще такой момент: Для двух этих случаев подходят регулярные выражения:

```
/<link.*=/
```

и

```
/<script.*=/
```

Хотя, как я понял, в первом случае мы должны найти `<link rel`, а во втором - `<script type`.  Почему эти выражения работают не так, как я думал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/<script.*src=/` не работает, потому что в вашей строке между `src` и `=` есть пробел `src =`, который ваше регулярное выражение не учитывает.

Учесть возможный пробел можно, например, так: `/<script.*src\s*=/` (пробел может быть и не один, поэтому квантифаер `*`, а не `?`)

Второй ваш вопрос не очень понятен. `.*` означает "любое количество произвольных символов", вдруг вы не в курсе. В этих строках есть и указанная вами первая часть строки и знак `=` после каких-то других символов, поэтому шаблоны срабатывают.

> Мне не понятно почему шаблоны срабатывают именно до последнего равно

Потому что по умолчанию регулярные выражения "жадные" (greedy). Под шаблон "произвольные символы в произвольном количестве" по умолчанию попадает максимум того, что туда может попасть. Для изменения этого поведения нужно использовать "не жадный" шаблон, например, вместо `.*` использовать `.*?` (если я правильно помню).

Comment: Спасибо. А что скажите насчет второй части вопроса?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Я как-раз дополнил ответ )

Comment: Мне не понятно почему шаблоны срабатывают именно до последнего равно, ведь по идее под реулярное выражение /<script.*=/ попадает и часть строки <script type=. Почему тогда регулярное выражение не остановилось, когда нашло первое равно?